# Spring MVC : redirect from POST to GET with attributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am quite new with Spring MVC. I would like to pass the model attributes from my POST method to the GET method. How could I do this ?

This is my POST service:

```
@PostMapping("reset-game")
public ModelAndView resetGame(@RequestBody String body, Model model) {
    
    String[] args = body.split("&");
    
    String mode = "";
    
    for (String arg : args) {
        if ("mode".equals(arg.split("=")[0])) {
            mode = arg.split("=")[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    
    Game resettedGame = gameService.resetGame(mode);
    
    model.addAttribute("mode", mode);
    model.addAttribute("boardSize", resettedGame.getBoardSize());
    model.addAttribute("moves", getJSONMoves(resettedGame.getMoves()).toString());
    
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/board");
}
```

And this is my GET service, the attributes defined in POST method are not passed to the GET method. Can anybody help me ? =)

```
@GetMapping("/board")
public String board() {
    return "board";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`RedirectAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) to achieve this.

```
@PostMapping("reset-game")
public ModelAndView resetGame(@RequestBody String body, RedirectAttributes redirectedAttributes) {
    
    String[] args = body.split("&");
    
    String mode = "";
    
    for (String arg : args) {
        if ("mode".equals(arg.split("=")[0])) {
            mode = arg.split("=")[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    
    Game resettedGame = gameService.resetGame(mode);
    
    redirectedAttributes.addFlashAttribute("mode", mode);
    redirectedAttributes.addFlashAttribute("boardSize", resettedGame.getBoardSize());
    redirectedAttributes.addFlashAttribute("moves", getJSONMoves(resettedGame.getMoves()).toString());
    
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/board");
}
```

From the docs, flash attributes does the following.

> After the redirect, flash attributes are automatically added to the
> model of the controller that serves the target URL.

On the `get` method, consume the parameters individually or via a model.

Assuming boardSize is integer and never null;

```
@GetMapping("/board")
public String board(@RequestParam String mode, @RequestParam int boardSize, @RequestParam String moves) {

    return "board";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I had to use the addFlashAttribute() method instead to make it work and also I had to return a RedirectView. Not sure why.. Anyway, my problem is solved, Thank you

Comment: oh yes, I missed that part. It should have been addFlashAttribute instead of addAttribute. I have updated the answer accordingly.